# Breadcrumb displays overridden page label instead of node title

Tags: 8, panels, breadcrumbs

Configuration:

- Drupal 8.1.5
- Panels 8.x-3.0-beta4
- Page Manager 8.x-1.0-alpha23
- Layout plugin 8.x-1.0-alpha22
- Panelizer 8.x-3.0-alpha2

Main menu:

- About

  - Team
  - Technology
  - ...

When visiting page `/about/team`, the breadcrumb shows `Home About`.

[image]

With Page Manager, I have overridden the default `/node/{node}`, and created a couple of panel variants based on path.

[image]

With this configuration, when visiting page `/about/team`, the breadcrumb shows `Home Node view`. So, instead of the node title for the `/about` page, the label of the custom page managed by Page Manager is displayed.

[image]

Is this a bug or expected? How to fix it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is an issue related with page_manager module.
Check out the d.org issue queue https://www.drupal.org/node/2665328